# Getting shape parameters from a beta probability density

Tags: python, density-function, beta-distribution

Is there a way to calculate the shape parameters $a$ and $b$ of a beta distribution having only its probability density function? This small example might clear a bit what I want (I work on Python):

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats

p = numpy.linspace(0, 1, 100)
betaD = scipy.stats.beta.pdf(p, a=12, b=12)
plt.plot(p, betaD)
plt.ylabel(r'$\theta$ |a, b')
```

[image]

So, I want to calculate betaD's $a$ and $b$.

Thanks!

Comment: If you have two distinct points from the density function (x1, f1) and (x2, f2), you could numerically solve for $a$ and $b$.  I don't believe there is any closed-form solution for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Could you tell us more explicitly the form in which you "have" this distribution?  Exactly what information will you use as the basis of your calculation?  After all, if you know the PDF (as you state), you know the distribution.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Whuber, I am not sure if I understood your question, but that's only because my relevant knowledge is less than limited. Anyway, I think I found a workaround which has nothing to do with calculating $a$ and $b$. Thank you for the answers.